# LINQ to NHibernate does not JOIN with subclass, whereas QueryOver does

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, queryover

I had this QueryOver query:

```
        var result = session.QueryOver<TopicSelection>()
            .Where(x => x.LacId == lac && x.RemoveDate == null)
            .List();
```

In a nutshell: TopicSelection is a base class, and one subclass has many-to-one property, with lazy=false and fetch=join.

When I used QueryOver, NHibernate created nice join and fetched additional data from many-to-one table. Which is great, one query is issued and I get everything.

When I changed it to LINQ to NHibernate:

```
        var result = session.Query<TopicSelection>()
            .Where(x => x.LacId == lac && x.RemoveDate == null)
            .ToList();
```

executed query does not contain JOIN. What is more, every time a many-to-one property is needed, an additional select is issued.

Is is a bug in LINQ in NHibernate? Can I instruct LINQ to NHibernate query to fetch data for subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are experiencing is a "NHibernate LINQ implementation" as is today. We can effectively do two things.

In case, that we can adjust the query to ask for a subclass, or the `many-to-one` property is *(could be)* declared on *base* `TopicSelection`, we can use `.Fetch()`

```
var result = session
     //.Query<TopicSelection>()
     .Query<TopicSelectionSubClass>()
     .Where(x => x.LacId == lac && x.RemoveDate == null)
     .Fetch(x => x.Category ) // the many-to-one property joined
     .ToList();
```

The second approach is even better. I would suggest that almost in any case. I.e. instead of any many-to-one mapping with `lazy="false" fetch="join"` - let's use:

- [19.1.5. Using batch fetching](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-batch)

Change the class mapping like this:

```
<class name="Category" batch-size="25" ...
```

That will change the 1+N select into 1+1 *(or 1+2)*. Small cite from docs:

> NHibernate can make efficient use of batch fetching, that is, NHibernate can load several uninitialized proxies if one proxy is accessed *(or collections)*. Batch fetching is an optimization of the lazy select fetching strategy. There are two ways you can tune batch fetching: on the class and the collection level.
>
> Batch fetching for classes/entities is easier to understand. Imagine you have the following situation at runtime: You have 25 Cat instances loaded in an ISession, each Cat has a reference to its Owner, a Person. The Person class is mapped with a proxy, lazy="true". If you now iterate through all cats and call cat.Owner on each, NHibernate will by default execute 25 SELECT statements, to retrieve the proxied owners.

Read more [here](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-batch)